# Rails test post create method RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've looked through all related posts, but can't figure out how to get my test to pass... I keep getting an error saying that Food.count should have changed by 1 but it didn't. I'm not sure if it has to do with the fact that my create method is building a relation?

```
def create
  @food = current_user.foods.build(food_params)

  if @food.save
    redirect_to user_path(@food.user_id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

---

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

validates :title, :kind, :image, presence: true

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

def Food.random_soup
    Food.all.where(kind: 'soup').shuffle
end
end
```

---

```
create_table "foods", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.string   "kind"
t.string   "title"
t.integer  "wins"
t.integer  "loses"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "image"
t.text     "recipe"
t.text     "description"
 end
```

---

```
  before(:each) do
  user = create(:user)
  sign_in(user)
end


describe "POST create" do
  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "creates a new food" do
      food_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:food)
      expect { post :create, :food => food_params }.to change(Food, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end


factory :food do |f|
  f.kind "soup"
  f.title "Clam Chowder"
  f.id 1
  f.image File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/app/assets/images/Canada.png'))
end
```

Comment: Have you tried placing a puts statement in your @food.save block to see if it prints?

Comment: I haven't but I had tried manually testing by creating a new food from my app, and the code executed correctly. The new food was also listed in my console

Comment: your create action looks fine. I might try explicting passing in the food params (i.e. `food_params = { kind: 'soup', title: 'clam chowder', image: 'test.jpg'}` )

Comment: nope still get the same error when I try that

Comment: Also, it might not work because `current_user` is nil

Comment: sorry check out my edit. I have a before(:each) that has a user

Comment: How about this instead:  `expect { post :create, :food => food_params }.to change{ Food.count }.by(1)`

Comment: remove `id` parameter from `FactoryGirl`

Comment: are you sure that you `@food` valid ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the factory is valid because I have a test that passes confirming that it is valid. As for the ID, I need to keep it so that I can test that the #show method works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to answer this without knowing more about your `@food` object.

There are a lot of things that could be going wrong (`food_params` is incomplete or malformed, `@food.save` is returning false, etc)

When a simple test like this is not passing the best thing to do (from past experience) is to throw a few "key" `binding.pry`s into your create method to see exactly what is going on when you run your test.

If you are not familiar with the gem `pry` I'd recommend reading the [README](https://github.com/pry/pry) but its essentially a way to stop execution and poke around with an IRB like REPL.

```
def create
  binding.pry
  # check to see what the original count is / current_user
  @food = current_user.foods.build(food_params)
  binding.pry
  # confirm that the relationship has been built (could be an issue with the way you are passing in params in the test and would be apparent here)
  # + check the return value of @food.save
  if @food.save
    redirect_to user_path(@food.user_id)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

with those 2 `pry`s you should be able to see exactly whats going on (either an issue with the `create` method or a minor issue with the test setup.

Good luck with getting the test to pass

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your test is working fine and that @food is actually invalid.

Without further details on the Food model all I can suggest is you try something like the following to determine what the errors are:

```
describe "POST create" do
  context "with invalid attributes" do
    it "should set errors" do
      food_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:food)
      post :create, :food => food_params
      puts assigns(:food).errors.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I edited my post to include more information. When I tried your suggestion, I was saying undefined method: errors for nil.